# Magento permissions

Tags: permissions

I've just managed to get the localhost version of a website I'm working on, onto our live server.

I'm having issues when it comes to permissions and who should own what etc.

When visiting the website it doesn't load the homepage, it brings up a download prompt instead.

I have set the permissions to www-data but obviously this isn't correct as like I said, it is prompting to download the website when opening the homepage.

What user should be assigned on the permissions, so the website is visible to the public?

Magento version is 1.9.2.2

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Default Permission as per magento standards

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 400 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 500 {} \; 
find var/ -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \; 
find media/ -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \;
find var/ -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \; 
find media/ -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;
chmod 700 includes
chmod 600 includes/config.php
```

Reference [Link](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html)

Comment: Thanks, but who should put these in place? the default web server user (www-data (Ubuntu) or the domain user? Because I put these in place and it asks to download the homepage when visiting the website.